What is this interpretation of Aristotle's Three Laws of Thought called?
I was reflecting on Aristotle's Three Laws of thoughts, and realized that they correspond nicely to the three necessary properties that any axiomatic system possesses.

First law: law of non-contradiction maps nicely to the requirement that any axiomatic system must discern between true and false statements.

Second law: law of identity maps nicely to the requirement that the axioms of an axiomatic system be self-evident. Also because A = A belongs to a temporally finite type there exists an immediate corollary that the number of axioms be finite in number (so cheap penny hooker tricks like True Arithmetic which circumvent Gödel's incompleteness theorem by making every true statement an axiom immediately violate the law of identity)

Third law: law of the excluded middle maps to the requirement that every well-formed formula evaluate to one and exactly one element of the set {⊤, ⊥}.


What is the name of this interpretation of Aristotle?

Axiomatic systems do not "discern" between true and false, only between provable and unprovable, there is a big difference. And that A = A "maps" to self-evidence of axioms is a very big stretch. In any case, self-evidence has long ceased to be a requirement if it ever was. Nor is there a requirement of finite number of axioms. Even Peano arithmetic has an axiom schema of induction, i.e. includes infinitely many axioms, one for each of its predicates. If A = A maps to anything formal it is to the requirement that the reference of constants must remain fixed in the course of a derivation.

Most of the people commenting or answering your question seem to think that by "axiom system" you mean a formal deductive system, but I presume that what you really mean is an axiomatic theory like Euclid's geometry. If I'm right, you might want to edit your question to clarify. However, modern logic no longer addresses such theories on their own terms but has reduced them to something of a formal caricature of what they were intended to be, so be aware of that.


Second law: law of identity maps nicely to the requirement that the axioms of an axiomatic system be self-evident.

The "law of identity" is, as far as I know, just the tautology p → p. (But in number theory, it could be the reflexive axiom that is part of the definition of equality. So, there is no unique analogy with current science.) Even though that tautology could be seen as self-evident, this doesn't mean that all axioms need to be self-evident. The most famous example is the parallel postulate in Euclid's axiomatic geometry which for millenia was seen as either obvious, though no one was able to prove it, or as self-evident, and thus not in need of any proof, until non-euclidean geometry was discovered in the 19th century.
There is still a relation between self-evidence and axioms, however. In a purely formal system, we can start from whatever axioms we want, as long as they are not contradictory. But when we want to somehow capture some concept or intuition, and want to precisely express the relevant characteristics of a concept, we do start from what seems at first intuitively self-evident. For instance the Peano axioms of number theory (aim to) express the characteristics of a natural number. They are not just an arbitrarily chosen formalism. On the other hand -- some axioms in set theory, for instance, even though they are also not arbitrarily chosen, are far from self-evident. Two examples are the axiom of infinity ("There is an infinite set") and the axiom of choice, which at first may be extremely hard to understand (and once you think you understand it a bit, it may still not be self-evident why its needed or when). Questions about the precise relations between axioms (and the concepts we want to express), the question whether a particular small group of axioms is minimal (none can be derived from any others and no extra ones are needed), and the question whether, even though the axioms don't seem contradictory, we can prove they are not and prove that they'll never lead to contradictions -- all those are also far from self-evident (as the history of mathematics has shown).
The notion (that is the feeling or experience) of self-evidence itself is less self-evidently clear than one may think. Self-evidence is a fundamental characteristic of all intuitive, apparently direct cognitions. As Efraim Fischbein writes in Intuition in Science and Mathematics (1987):

An intuitive cognition is self-consistent, self-justifiable and self-explanatory. If we affirm the whole is bigger than each of its parts, that every number has a successor, or that two points determine a straight line, we feel that these statements are true by themselves without the need for any justification. (p.43)


One may assume that obviousness expresses, to a certain extent, the behavioral meaningfulness of a notion.

Mathematicians have learned to distrust those kind of feelings.

In modern usage, the law of identity is more commonly used to refer to a relation between individuals, conventionally written =, such that every individual is identical with itself. In Aristotle, it is difficult to determine a single sense of his three laws. Are they about propositions, about individuals, about properties, or about rational beliefs? These distinctions are important to us but he runs them together.

+1 However, "In a purely formal system, we can start from whatever axioms we want, as long as they are not contradictory. " I'm no Bumble, but I believe a formal system can embrace dialetheia. Thus, it is possible to build a system that accepts true contradictions. "Dialetheism is the view that there are dialetheias. If we define a contradiction as a couple of sentences of which one is the negation of the other, or as a conjunction of such sentences, then dialetheism amounts to the claim that there are true contradictions."

The three principle have little to do with modern axiomatic.
They must be understood in the context of Ancient Greek Philosophy, and particularly the discussion regarding essence, change, predication.
Law of NC means that something cannot be A and not-A: "the name has a meaning and has one meaning; it is impossible, then, that being a man should mean precisely not being a man (Met, Bk.IV, 1006a29-1006b18)".
Identity means that essences (universals) do not change: what is essentially white cannot become not-white. Change typical of the material world cannot be accounted by logic alone, but requires other principles (Physics). Compare it with the discussion in Plato's Parmenides: "as Socrates himself emphasizes at Phaedo 101b, it would be monstrous to say that something is made larger by something small. This is an instance of a general claim we might call “No Causation by Contraries: For any property F, nothing that is F could make something possess a property that is contrary to the property of being F."
Law of EM means that something must be either white or not-white: "there cannot be an intermediate between contradictories (Met. Bk.IV, 1011b23)."

@local - obviously yes: LNC and LEM are still valid laws of classical propositional logic.

@local - see Axiomatic system.


The law of non-contradiction “not (A and non-A)” is not
only required for the axioms of an axiom system but for any
proposition – at least in the usual logic, which excludes
paraconsistent logic.

Today it is not required that axioms of an axiom system
must be self-evident.
The concept of self-evidence is ill-defined due
to different reasons: The basic terms of an axiom system are
undefined. Often people do not agree about what is self-evident.
Axioms are requirements, not self-evident propositions.

The law of excluded middle is not necessarily required
for an axiom system. Axiom systems may rely on many-valued
logic.


I question the whole enterprise of your post to set in close relation the three laws of Aristotle from above with modern axiomatics, see also axiomatic system and proof theory.
Aside: I do not understand the meaning of the law of identity “A = A”.

It means that self-evident propositions must be self-evident. So, for instance, you ought to regard the first four axioms of euclidean geometry like applications of the law of identity. A line is breathless length follows from the identity of a line, a circle is a locus of equidistant points follows from the identity of a circle, etc....
